# Perl code to generate secret key for HMAC SHA256 signing?

Tags: perl, hmac, sha256, secret-key

I'm planning to use code similar to [Amazon AWS samples](http://aws.amazon.com/code/2482?_encoding=UTF8&queryArg=searchQuery&x=0&fromSearch=1&y=0&searchPath=code&searchQuery=signed) to authenticate signed API requests. So users will have something like:

```
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256_base64);
my $digest = hmac_sha256_base64 ($request, $self->{SecretKey});
```

and attach `$digest` as a parameter to their request URI. The server-side will use the same algorithm to create a digest from the client URI and compare that to the value sent by the client.

What I can't find is **Perl** support for generating the SecretKey of the correct length to use when generating HMAC SHA256 digest.

For my Amazon AWS account I'm being given a 40 ASCII character base64 encoded string.

How do I generate a proper secret-key for my clients?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a PBKDF2 algorithm.  PBKDF2 = "Password-based Key Derivation Function (#2)".   It is defined in PKCS #5 ([RFC 2898](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2898.html)).   This is the recommended way to derive a key from a password.  You will need a salt, as well. A typical iteration count is 1000.

[This page](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/software/) says it has a perl implementation of PBKDF2.  I haven't tried it.

Apparently there is also a `Crypto::PBKDF2`, but it is saddled with dependencies you may not want.

---

**EDIT**

I just tried Anthony Thyssen's perl program for pbkdf2 - it works great. Simple, easy.

Comment: Thanks.  I assume you're referring to http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/software/pbkdf2.pl but what I don't have is $password.  I want to generate a unique shared secret key for a given user access key (which I've already handed out.  There's no login involved to the API.  SO do I just create a random internal "password" to act as my input to pbkdf2?